# In ios/xcode is it ok to have autolayout turned on but have no constraints

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a view controller that is working better without any constraints (formatting looks better on all iphone screens). However, I'm using autolayout for the rest of my view controllers so it's turned on at a global level.

Everything seems to be fine (there are no warnings) having no constraints on this view controller. 
Also, this VC has only has static text content and the app is locked in portrait mode.

I'm wondering if I'm missing something and need to have some constraints?

Edit: I have cleared all the constraints, so there aren't any default constraints when I look at the VC. When I select "Add missing constraints" the VC formatting looks bad.

Comment: it will generate constraints when you build the project.

Comment: I have cleared any constraints in storyboard. Does XCode still add constraints when building?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with Xcode 5, not adding any constraints to a hierarchy will make Xcode add a default constraints. You are seeing those when you run your app and reach the view controller. However, if you rotate your view, you'll notice that these constraints are very basic. It would be better to have your own constraints, but if you only support one orientation, these constraints are fine.

Here is a suggestion; run your project with the default constraints, and inspect in runtime to see what they are, and get ideas how to implement them in Xcode.

Comment: Please see edit. I have cleared any constraints in storyboard. Does XCode still add constraints when building?

Comment: @djburdick Yes! Xcode adds default constraints for you.

Comment: OK, it's interesting that when I do the "Add missing constraints" in storyboard, it messes up the formatting, but when building with no visible constraints, it looks good. I would think XCode would add the same default constraints in those two cases.

Comment: @djburdick The default constraints are simple constraints to keep everything in place. When you use `Add Missing Constraints`, it tries to create fitting constraints according to some heuristics (basically what Xcode thinks is "correct"). I never liked that option - you should add constraints yourself.